# Pivot slicer not coordinating with selected filters

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, slicers

I already worked with slicers without problems, but this time I noticed that in this pivot my slicer doesn't update properly according to filters selected. 
'Allow multiple filters per field' is unticked, so the slicer depends on other filters and thus should be able to hide data that has no values in the filtered pivot...logically.

But why it still shows data that has no values?

Thank you for any help

[image: Pivot slicer data with no values still showing even after changing settings]

[image: Allow multiple filters per field is unticked]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after tons of tries.

It was because I was filtering the pivot table using a "fabricated/forced" filter on pivot columns as you can see in the firt picture and as recommanded here : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/filtering-a-pivot-table-on-a-calculated-field/31312a31-8e9a-401b-acb0-ed575d9cb397

which turned out to be a VERY bad idea causing a lot of troubles in the pivot.

Instead, when using a regular filter(drag & droped in Filters in Field list window), everything works and updates well in the pivot.